# 2-bromobutane absolute configuration from structural formula to 3D

Tags: stereochemistry, isomers, chirality

For the 2-bromobutane drawn below, given the 3d image I can tell it is R configuration
[image: Ball and stick mode]

[Annotated from source:](http://wps.prenhall.com/wps/media/objects/340/348272/Instructor_Resources/Chapter_05/Text_Images/FG05_04.JPG)

However, given the structural formula I can't figure out how to get this 3d shape correctly.

Structural formula:
[image: Structural Formula]

When I try to visualise it I get two possibilities:
[image: 3D models]

My sticking point is: when moving the H (the lowest priority group here) to the back, which way (to the left or right) does the CH3 go? Depending on which I draw the answer changes.

Comment: This is a [Fischer projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fischer_projection). By convention, the horizontal groups come towards you and the vertical ones go away.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks. By the way, how do I close the question or select an answer if  the answer is in the comments?

Comment: Well, that's the thing, you cannot select an answer from the comments. You have basically two options now. Hope that @f'' is considering to write a small answer (or maybe someone else), or when that does not happen, write one yourself how you figured out the solution. Ideally it should contain a little more information than just a comment.

Comment: @f'' How can you be sure it is a Fischer projection? The page you link says, _The use of Fischer projections in non-carbohydrates is discouraged, as such drawings are ambiguous when confused with other types of drawing._ If it was a Fischer projection, would it not be more natural to have Br at one side of the "cross", and then have the C-C bonds vertical? Maybe the answer to this is, if you know it is a Fischer projection, the exact configuration can be inferred from that. If you do not know if it is a Fischer projection, the precise stereoisomerism cannot be inferred from the "flat" diagram.